# Php formatting Google places output array

Tags: php, google-maps, google-places-api

I need to format the output of the Google Places address. I want to remove everything to the left of the last separator line and also remove the country (that is also contained in the output). Here is an example:

**Google output**

```
[address] => Rua da Liberdade - Aparecida, Santos - SP, Brasil
[lat] => -23.9713022
[lng] => -46.3037377
[zoom] => 14
[place_id] => EjBSLiBkYSBMaWJlcmRhZGUgLSBBcGFyZWNpZGEsIFNhbnRvcyAtIFNQLCBCcmF6aWwiLiosChQKEgkfHjkSSwLOlBFOJU9QNBXTDhIUChIJUcEPMUYCzpQRAVML1qqHE18
[name] => Rua da Liberdade
[street_name] => Rua da Liberdade
[street_name_short] => R. da Liberdade
[state] => São Paulo
[state_short] => SP
[country] => Brasil
[country_short] => BR
```

**What I need...**

<strike>Rua da Liberdade -</strike> Aparecida, Santos - SP<strike>, Brasil</strike>

i.e.

```
Aparecida, Santos - SP
```

To remove the country, I tried to use `str_replace` using the key `country`:

```
$locations = get_field( 'profile-location', 'user_' .$userid );
if ( $locations ) {
    $location_format = str_replace( $locations['country'], '', $locations['address'] );
}
return $location_format;
```

Comment: Are they always formatted `something here - some other stuff - more stuff`?

Comment: I edited my question

Comment: You should re-arrange words to be nicer question, i.g. your topic should be question. You need to make a good explanation like I don't know it at all, then you will get the good answer back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract the pieces of information that you want from the `$locations` array into a new array, skipping the pieces that are not present. This can then be `implode`d to make the output address:

```
$address = [];
if (isset($locations['neighborhood'])) $address[] = $locations['neighborhood'];
if (isset($locations['city'])) $address[] = $locations['city'];
if (isset($locations['state'])) $address[] = $locations['state'];
elseif (isset($locations['state_short'])) $address[] = $locations['state_short'];

$address = implode(', ', $address);
echo $address;
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/hZm03)

Comment: Sometimes the output changes to:  [address] => Santos, SP, Brasil

Comment: @SHARKDEV What does the rest of the array look like in that case? And what is your expected output?

Comment: Expected output is always without the avenue street, the like, and removing the country, always leaving everything without these other things, google does not return consistent data ..

Comment: @SHARKDEV give my edited code a try. Without seeing a lot of sample data it's hard to tell whether it will work but based on your sample and description it should be close

Comment: I believe that a regex, removing the address already solves, leaving the country is not so bad

Comment: What's your expected output for that case?

Comment: The idea is to always follow a pattern: Neighborhood, City, State

Comment: Thank you very much for your time, it does solve my problem.